# How do I change "/permissive- (Standards conformance)" in the settings of vs2022 ？

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I tried to follow [this URL to operate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170), but I can't find these options, like "C/C++", "Language" or "Conformance mode", which is mentioned at the end of article. Did VS change the location or name of this option?

Comment: From Project > Foo Properties (Alt+F7), I'm seeing my just created moments ago C++ project's Foo Property Page, Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Language have a **Conformance mode** that I have set to Yes `/permissive-`.

Comment: What type of project do you have in VS? Is it a C++ project?

Comment: On a new project C++ settings does not appear until you have added the first C++ source file to the project.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your project's properties page? Not the solution property.